# Meshlab triangle/surface creation

Tags: mesh, meshlab

I'm currently repairing and cleaning a mesh in the software MeshLab and I was wondering if it could be possible to manually select three vertex from the data set and create a triangular face using those 3 vertex, or maybe it could be possible to apply a "local triangulation" in a very small domain containing those three vertex?

Any idea or guide on how to proceed would be appreciated, I have browsed through MeshLab's filters but have found nothing so far.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, that is not possible in meshlab.

But it is very easy to do manually with a text editor if you already know the index of the three vertex.

1. Export your mesh in .ply ascii file format (uncheck the "binary encoding" checkbox in the .ply options).
2. Open your file in a text editor.
3. Increment the "element face" number in the line 12
4. Write "3 " and the three indexes in a new line at the end of the file.